# problem\How to activate Elecard Direct Show Decoder filter

Tags: c++, c

I have bought license from `Elecard` for their `AVC\H264` Decoder

Following that code:

```
HRESULT DShowPlayer::ActivateFilter(IBaseFilter *filter)
{

    static const GUID KEY_GUID = { 0xb9d44b32, 0xd34a, 0x11e8, { 0x88, 0x16,  0x10 , 0x20 ,0xFB ,0x45 ,0x87, 0x53 } };

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    IModuleConfig* IMC;
    hr = filter->QueryInterface(&IMC);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {    
        hr = IMC->SetValue(&KEY_GUID, NULL);
        IMC->Release();
    }
    return hr;

}
```

I am trying to activate my filter ( The number above was changed of course) 
Calling that function i pass the `Elecard` Decoder filter after it was added to the graph.

I am getting the hr of

```
hr = IMC->SetValue(&KEY_GUID, NULL);
```

is Invalid pointer

Does someone activate `Elecard` Decoder via code.

BTW, Activating the filter via the Module Config Checker works as expected

Thanks!

Comment: The sample documentation passes `KEY_GUID` directly instead of its address. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry , i just enter incorrect GUID
entering incorret GUID gives pointer error